# Cannot find connected devices. Emulator start failed with: Cannot resolve the specified connected device by the provided index or identifier.

Tags: nativescript

I'm learning NativeScript and 
When running `tns platform add android` I receive the following error:
I follow this step:

1. Run the command prompt as an Administrator.
2. @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
3. choco install googlechrome -y
4. choco install nodejs-lts -y
5. choco install jdk8 -y
6. choco install android-sdk -y
7. "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;25.0.2" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository"
8. @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://nativescript.org/setup/win-avd'))"
9. choco install androidstudio -y
10. npm i -g nativescript
11. tns doctor I see  "No issues were detected" you are good to go!
12. tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-tutorial
13. cd HelloWorld
14. tns run android

Error: 
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Cannot resolve the specified connected device by the
 provided index or identifier. To list currently connected devices and verify th
at the specified index or identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exi
sts, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device  --available-device
s'.

Comment: You would need either a real device connected or emulators installed on your PC. If you don't have a real device you can download and install system images for Android Virtual Devices (a.k.a. emulators) - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 3):

You can see all packages/images of the devices that you can download - `avdmanager list`. Choose the one you need and install:

`cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`

`./sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"`

`./sdkmanager --licenses`

And create the image:

`avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"`

if you will get an error, as I got:

> .android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded

run:

`touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg`

Now `tns run android` should work.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you are at $ANDROID_HOME\tools\bin (the default path is .\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin) in the command line.

Use the sdkmanager to install the package.

```
   sdkmanager “system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86”
```

To see the list of SDK packages use

```
sdkmanager --list
```

If you receive a "Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:ository" error, use:

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

Then create the AVD by using

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use real devices, you have to enable USB debugging in the developer options. After that, you can see the the application identifier as listed by `tns device list-applications`