# tns run doesn't load the app in emulator in Mac

Tags: macos, nativescript, android-virtual-device

```
tns device android --available-devices

You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.

Available emulators
Calculated width 89 is above terminal width: 80. You can try using smaller value for min_column_width. Current value is: 15
┌───────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ Device Name   │ Platform │ Version   │ Device        │ Image         │ Error Help │
│               │          │           │ Identifier    │ Identifier    │            │
│ Pixel_2_API_R │ Android  │           │               │ Pixel_2_API_R │            │
└───────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

tns doctor also lists good results

```
✔ Getting environment information 

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 10.0.0 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 7.0.7 and the latest available version is 7.0.8.
```

However, when I run  `tns run android` I see the following:

```
    You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: No emulator image available for device identifier 'undefined'.
To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.
```

still, a plain tns device doesn't list anything.

```
tns device
You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.

Connected devices & emulators
Searching for devices...
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

`$ emulator @Pixel_2_API_R` just launches the emulator though.

when I run `tns run android`
For some reason, it is not able to launch the emulator and run the app. What am I missing?

Comment: tns run ios launches the ios emulator but doesn't load the app..... This is what I see in the terminal : tns run ios --force
You are using the deprecated nsconfig.json file. Just be aware that NativeScript 7 has an improved nativescript.config.(js|ts) file for when you're ready to upgrade this project.
The current Xcode version 10.0.0 will not be supported in the next release of NativeScript. Consider updating your Xcode to latest official version.
Searching for devices...
Unable to find applicable devices to execute operation. Ensure connected devices are trusted and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped. I could execute tns run android and it loads the app on the emulator

[Cannot find connected devices. Emulator start failed with: Cannot resolve the specified connected device by the provided index or identifier.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243197/cannot-find-connected-devices-emulator-start-failed-with-cannot-resolve-the-sp?rq=1)